# Programming ESP32-S3 WROOM with a flexy pin board

Tags: esp32, upload

I am using ESP32-S3-WROOM-1-N8 module https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/espressif-systems/ESP32-S3-WROOM-1-N8/15200089 .
I have compared pinout of all Wroom modules ESP32 ESP32-S3 as well as ESP32-WROVER have all the programming pins in exactly same positions so I was expecting this programmer to work for any of these modules. I am looking at GND, 3v3, EN, RX, TX, GPIO0.

I am using this flexy pin board from aliexpress https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005004605613498.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.91.21ef5c5f6R74vM&gatewayAdapt=glo2deu

When Uploading sketch I am getting following error:

```
StopIteration
[6848] Failed to execute script 'esptool' due to unhandled exception!

Chip is ESP32-S3
Features: WiFi, BLE
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: 7c:df:a1:ec:d1:f0
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 921600
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

[image]

Looks like it failed while configuring flash memory, I have gone through esptool's codebase on Github it seems to fail at this function https://github.com/espressif/esptool/blob/master/esptool/loader.py#L1167
I am not experienced with all this so can't figure out what is the issue.
On board config, I have set

```
Flash mode: QIO 80MHz
Flash size: 8MB
```

I have selected `ESP32S3 Dev Module` as the board
ESP32 Library `v2.0.6`

Update: When I opened the serial monitor, it is showing following

```
ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0x7 (TG0WDT_SYS_RST),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x40049b21
invalid header: 0xa5ff005a
```

Am I wrong in assuming all these modules can be programmed with this programmer?

Thanks in advance

Update 2:
Changing upload speed from 921600 to 115200 fixed it, but the module still errored when running it.
Serial monitor shows following:

```
ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0x1 (POWERON),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fce3808,len:0x44c
load:0x403c9700,len:0xbec
load:0x403cc700,len:0x2920
entry 0x403c98d8
[    81][D][esp32-hal-cpu.c:244] setCpuFrequencyMhz(): XTAL: 40 / 1 = 40 Mhz, APB: 80000000 Hz
E (491) psram: PSRAM ID read error: 0x00ffffff
[    83][W][esp32-hal-psram.c:71] psramInit(): PSRAM init failed!
[   120][D][esp32-hal-rmt.c:615] rmtInit():  -- TX RMT - CH 0 - 1 RAM Blocks - pin 48
```

Which went away after I disabled PSRAM in upload setting.
Now I seem to be able to program and run it but the serial monitor is only showing debug messages, the message I am trying to print to serial is not showing up.
Also blink sketch is also not working for BUILTIN_LED as well as GPIO1

Comment: try lower baud rate

Comment: I've never used these programming adapters, but to me it looks like the ESP32 module is supposed to be placed with the WiFi antenna to the left. What does the documentation say?

Comment: There is no documentation. That WIFI antenna is from ESP-12 module socket. I have checked continuity for few pins and they confirm that is the way the module is mounted.

Comment: @Juraj that actually helped, though it was already in lowest 921600 I increased it to 115200

Now I was able to upload the sketch but it failed while running it. I ll update the Question

Comment: 921600 is almost 1 mega

Comment: did you select S3 version in Tools menu?

Comment: Yes. and the PSRAM error went away when I disable the PSRAM option in the upload config.

Comment: ever get this working @AnilMaharjan

Comment: @NightWolf yes I did.